# Puppeteer - (Page.navigate: Cannot navigate to invalid URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

here, I have an list of array My URL is from an array

URL:

```
url= result[urls]
console.log(url)
```

Output:

```
books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html
```

when I used this:

```
 await page.goto('"http://' + url + '"');
```

I got an error something like this:

```
 Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL
```

**Note**: When i used this instead:

```
await page.goto("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/soumission_998/index.html");
```

**Then It Works**

Anyone have idea about this?? How to solve this error `:)`

Comment: What happens when you try this `await page.goto('http://' + url);`?

Answer (score 1):

If SMTH answer didn't work. You could give `` await page.goto(`https://${url}`); `` a try.

Answer (score 1):

I think that its your quotation marks

```js
 await page.goto('"http://' + url + '"');
```

Should be

```js
 await page.goto('http://' + url);
```

Answer (score -6):

**Step 1.** First, install Node.js

**Step 2.** Install NPM

**Step 3.** Run

```
npm install -g magepack
```

**Step 4.** Run

```
composer require creativestyle/magesuite-magepack
```

**Step 5.** enter `magepack` to check the version.

**Step 6.**

```
magepack generate --cms-url="{{CMS_PAGE_URL}}" --category-url="{{CATEGORY_PAGE_URL}}" --product-url="{{PRODUCT_PAGE_URL}}"`
```

Add your URLs in this format.

```
magepack generate --cms-url="http://local.com/" --category-url="http://local.com/mens-accessories.html" --product-url="http://local.com/shirt-lock.html"`
```

**Step 7.**

```
magepack bundle
```

**Step 8.**
Once you made sure Magepack Magento module is installed, what is left is to enable it via admin panel under Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Developer or CLI:

```
bin/magento config:set dev/js/enable_magepack_js_bundling 1
```

**Step 9.**

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: This is in no way related to the question and just makes to user install unnecessary stuff.